# Allow multiple selection of user roles

Tags: plugins

By deafult we are only allowed to select one roles per user. Due to my website requirement, I have to enable multiple selection of user roles. I have searched but cannot find any answers on this. I also have tried plugins for creating custom fields but no luck at all.

Does anyone ever tried this or have any plugin suggestion or code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom role that will hold capabilities of the multiple roles you want and assign that single custom role.

or you can simple do this by code, a user's role can be set by creating an instance of the WP_user class, and calling the add_role() ex:

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_role( 'editor' );
```